# A graph with bounded degree has typical distance at least $(1-\varepsilon)\log n/\log d_{\max}$ with high probability

Tags: probability, graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $(G_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a graph sequence that has a bounded degree, i.e., $\max_{v \in [n]}d_v = d_{\max} \leq K$ and $G_n$ is connected for every $n \geq 1$. Let $[n]$ be the set of vertices of $G_n$.

**To show:** For all $\varepsilon > 0$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(H_n \leq (1-\varepsilon)\log n/\log d_{\max}) = 0.
$$
The random variable $H_n$ is a typical distance. Draw two vertices $U_1$ and $U_2$ uniformly at random. Then $H_n = \operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2)$, where the operator $\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}$ measures the shortest distance between $U_1$ and $U_2$ in graph $G_n$.

**My attempt:** Well not much since I don't know how to analyse this event. The random variable $H_n < \infty$ a.s. for all $n \geq 1$ because $G_n$ is connected. Using the definition of $H_n$:
$$
\mathbb{P}(H_n \leq (1-\varepsilon)\log n/\log d_{\max}) = \mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) \leq (1-\varepsilon)\log n/\log d_{\max}).
$$
Let $k_n := \lceil (1-\varepsilon)\log n/\log d_{\max} \rceil$. Then
$$
\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) \leq k_n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{k_n}\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = k). 
$$
So now, what is $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = k)$ for $0 \leq k \leq k_n$? I was thinking
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = k) &= \sum_{u,v \in [n]}\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = k|U_1 = u, U_2 = v)\mathbb{P}(U_1 = u, U_2 = v)\\
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{u,v \in [n]}\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = k|U_1 = u, U_2 = v)
\end{align*}
If $k = 0$, then $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = 0|U_1 = u, U_2 = v) = 1$ if and only if $u = v$, otherwise the probability is zero.  So
$$
\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{dist}_{G_n}(U_1, U_2) = 0) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{u \in [n]}1 = \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Great! But how about for other $k \neq 0$?

Comment: You start talking about $H_n$ before you define it. Is what follows the problem statement - the distance between two vertices chosen uniformly at random - the definition of $H_n$?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any node $i \in [n]$ and distance $k$, there can be at most $d_\max^k$ nodes at distance $k$ from $i$. Hence

$$\mathbb P(H_n \le h) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor h \rfloor} \mathbb P(H_n = k) \le \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor h \rfloor} \frac{d_\max^k}{n} \le \frac{d_\max^{h+1} - 1}{n(d_\max - 1)},$$

where $d_\max > 1$ since the $G_n$ are connected. For $h = (1-\epsilon)\log(n)/\log(d_\max)$, the RHS tends to $0$.

Comment: But for $n = 2$, there would be only two vertices and they form an edge. So $d_{\max} = 1$ in this case, right? Also, why can there be at most $d_{\max}^k$ nodes at distance $k$ from $i$? Are we chosing one vertex uniformly at random? But $H_n$ is the distance between two vertices that are drawn uniformly at random? So shouldn't there be $n^2$ instaead of $n$?

Comment: @Vicky (1) That only works for $n=2$, and we've assumed the $G_n$ are connected for all $n$. (2) Because the degree is bounded by $d_\max$, just think about it. (3) The bound is the same for every $U_1$, so we can just fix one and average over $U_2$.

Comment: A path of length $k$ has $k+1$ vertices. That's all I can think of, and so I don't see how the number of vertices at distance $k$ from $i$ is related to the boundedness of the degree.

Comment: @Vicky To choose a path of length $k$ starting from node $a$, you first pick a node $b$ from the neighbours of $a$, then a node $c$ from the neighbours of $b$, and so on. You have to make $k$ choices, each one from at most $d_\max$ alternatives. Hence there are at most $d_\max^k$ paths.

Comment: Sorry to draw your attention back to this but can you explain the last two inequalities, and how the choice of $h$ implies the conclusion?

Comment: The first inequality is explained in the above comments. The second is just the sum of a geometric progression, and the choice of $h$ gives $d_{\max}^h \sim n^{1-\epsilon}$, so the RHS is $O(n^{-\epsilon})$. @meeeeee

Comment: Ah, thank you so much!